# windows 7 & vista gets IIS "under construction" error - xp get webpage fine!

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, windows-xp, windows-7

the entire 2003 server has several websites on the zone that works great!
the new one from today is working only on XP and not on 7 or vista

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your 7/vista boxes are trying to talk ipv6 to your webserver.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is a web application that you are trying to access. Do they have a standard IE version? You may need to look at that.